# SwiftUI var: willSet, didSet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this kind of code in a SwiftUI app:

```
@Published var myFlag = false {
    willSet {
        ... useful code ...
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

It more or less works, but to exactly get what I need I want to have something like that:

```
@Published var myFlag = false {
    didSet {
        ... useful code ...
        objectDidChange.send()
    }
}
```

For the simple reason that I would like to be notified once myFlag is updated rather than before. It doesn't seem to work that way though.
Is there some other way to get what I want?

Beside I am using this code:

```
.onReceive(self.appState.$myFlag) {...}
```

inside ContentView.swift

Comment: The `objectDidChange.send()` is called automatically whenever @Published property is set, so your code at least redundant (or might be even harmful). What do you try to do with that code? Would you show client of this observable object? Or, better, complete testable snapshot?

Comment: @Asperi; I need to be able to do some side processing (i.e. ... useful code ...), like I can do in willSet. But I also want to send the update signal after the value has been updated rather than before. If I just remove objectWillChange.send() from willSet. Will that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Published` automatically publishes when the property is at `willSet`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published

If you prefer to publish during `didSet` remove `@Published` and publish manually.

```
import SwiftUI
class ManualOObject: ObservableObject {
    var someValue: Int = 0{
        willSet{
            print("willSet - \(someValue)")
        }
        didSet{
            print("didSet - \(someValue)")
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    init() {
        for n in 0...5 {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(n)) {
                print("n = \(n.description)")
                            self.someValue = n
                        }
        }
    }
}
struct ManualOOView: View {
    @StateObject var manualOObject = ManualOObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(manualOObject.someValue.description).onReceive(manualOObject.objectWillChange, perform: { _ in
            print("UI received = \(manualOObject.someValue)")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to try but, if I remove "@Published" the code in my ContentView.swift: 
".onReceive(self.appState.$myFlag)"
does not work anymore. I get this error:
"Expression type '(_, "@escaping" (_.Output) -> Void) -> some View' is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: I put an example on how to use onReceive in the code. Also, if you need more specific work done use MVVM. Keep the View clear of functions, a ViewModel would do all the work.